# "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals" error. unable to understand why?

Tags: matlab

I have these 3 functions

```
function r = RingRead(n,p)
    r=( p * RingReadggg(n-1,p))+( (1-p)* RingReadggb(n-1,p));
end

function r = RingReadggb(n , p)
    if n <= 1
        r = 0;
    else
        r = ((1-p)* RingReadggb(n-1,p) )+ p^2 +( p(1-p)* RingReadggb(n-2,p));
    end
end

function r = RingReadggg(n , p)
    if n == 1
        r = p;
    else
        r = (p+p(1-p)+( (1-p)^2 * RingReadggb(n-2,p)));
    end
end
```

Below given program uses above given functions.

```
for p = 0.50:0.05:1
    r =  RingRead(4,p);
    plot(p,r)
    hold on       
end
```

When i run this it gives error

> **??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
>   logicals.**
>
> Error in ==> RingRead>RingReadggg at 18
>               r = (p+p(1-p)+( (1-p)^2 * RingReadggb(n-2,p)));
>
> Error in ==> RingRead at 3
>           r=( p * RingReadggg(n-1,p))+( (1-p)* RingReadggb(n-1,p));
>
> Error in ==> RingAvailability at 2    r =  RingRead(4,p);

Comment: please give us some context and describe what you are trying to do with your functions. "Here code, you fix" are not exactly good questions...

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 2):

Your code crashes right here:

```
r = (p+p(1-p)+( (1-p)^2 * RingReadggb(n-2,p)))
```

n is 3 and p is 0.5

but what is

```
p(1-p)
```

supposed to be? do you mean `p * (1-p)` ?

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, the error occurs on this line:

```
r = (p+p(1-p)+( (1-p)^2 * RingReadggb(n-2,p)));
```

By `p(1-p)`, do you really mean `p * (1-p)`? Entered as `p(1-p)` is interpreted as indexing into `p` at the index `1-p`. Try changing the line to:

```
r = (p+p*(1-p)+( (1-p)^2 * RingReadggb(n-2,p)));
```

It looks like you have the same issue in RingReadggb as well.